# Use a csv file as the backend for SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, sqlalchemy

I have a python tool that uses sqlalchemy to connect to Postgres and MYSQL. I do this by modifying only the parameters to `create_engine`. However, it is possible that I have to work with the DB dump in the form of a csv file. Is there any way to pass the csv to `create_engine`.

I could simply load the contents of the csv into a local database and pass that to sqlalchemy, but it will be great if I can completely avoid the db while dealing with csv files.

Comment: Perhaps your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662631/how-to-copy-from-csv-file-to-postgresql-table-with-headers-in-csv-file

Comment: I would rather not do that. I don't want to load the csv into a db and then pass that db to sqlalchemy. I want a way to directly pass the csv to sqlalchemy.

Comment: What does it mean to "pass the csv to sqlalchemy"?

Comment: I mean that sqlalchemy should work with csv instead of a database. Ideal, csv is passed as a parameter to create_engine method of sqlalchemy.

Comment: It's not possible. SQLAlchemy only emits SQL. How are you going to execute SQL against a CSV file, except by loading it into a SQL database?

Comment: I thought SQLAlchemy is converting the contents of the DB into corresponding classes and objects. If that is the case, it should be able to parse the csv (or other flatfiles) and create the corresponding objects, right?

Comment: Not quite. SQLAlchemy allows you load and save rows into a DB, as though they were objects, by emitting SQL. It has no support for CSV as a backend.

Comment: oh thank you. In that case I might have to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580497/database-on-the-fly-with-scripting-languages